# PDE for the area-preserving non-parametric curve shortening flow?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, curvature

In dimension $1$, it is well-known that the motion of a (unparametrized) plane curve $\{(x,f(x,t);\,x \in I \subset \mathbb R)\}$ under the curve shortening flow can be encoded by the PDE $$\partial_t f = \frac{\partial_{xx} f}{1+|\partial_x f|^2} = \partial_x\left(\arctan(\partial_x f)\right),\quad x\in I.$$ We also suppose that $f(x,0) \geq 0$ for all $x \in I$ so that $f(x,t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $x\in I$ (thanks to the parabolic maximum principle). It is clear that if $I = \mathbb R$, then the area under the plane curve is conserved since $$\int_{\mathbb R} \partial_t f \,dx = \arctan(\partial_x f)\Big|_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} = 0.$$ But if we insist that $I = [a,b]$ being a finite subset of $\mathbb R$, along with the Dirichlet boundary conditions $f(a,t) = f(b,t) \equiv 0$ for all $t\geq 0$. Then the PDE above does not preserve the area anymore, as $\int_a^b \partial_t f \,dx \neq 0$. Is there a way to modify the aforementioned PDE so that the corresponding curve shortening flow with Dirichlet boundary datum is area-preserving? I googled hard for the relevant literature but unfortunately I didn't find anything useful for my question. Thanks for any help!
**Edit:** I do want the long time behavior of the "modified PDE" to converge to a portion of a circle that joins $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ (which has constant curvature).

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect a modification of the equation to work for Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Generally speaking, you don't get a conserved quantity for any equation $u_t = (F(u_x))_x$ (where $F'(p)>0$) for Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Instead, a 'conserved' quantity appears with Neumann boundary conditions.  (I put 'conserved' in quotes, because, of course, you actually get $$\int_\mathbb{R} \partial_t u\,\mathrm{d}x = F(\beta)-F(\alpha)$$ when you impose the Neumann boundary conditions $u_x(a,t)=\alpha$ and $u_x(b,t)=\beta$.)

Comment: You probably should make more precise the kind of flow you are expecting. For the area to be preserved, you cannot hope to shorten curves in general (if $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and the graph of $f$ is a half circle, then it is the shortest curve in the upper half plane with these end value and the given enclosed area). However you could build a flow that will make the curvature constant in the limit, would that work for you?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner "However you could build a flow that will make the curvature constant in the limit, would that work for you?" That's exactly what I want, I want the large time behavior resembles a portion of a circle. However, I do want the dynamics to preserve the mass and positivity. If such modification of the original equation is possible, I do not care whether it is "shortening the (length of the ) curve" anymore.

Comment: @RobertBryant For some reason, I really want the Dirichlet boundary to be imposed. I admit that there are potentially many (or no) ways to "modify" the origin PDE such that the mass and positivity of the solution is preserved. I do not care whether the modification is "shortening the (length of the ) curve" or not...

Comment: Since you are not being specific about what counts as a 'modification' of the heat equation, how about the following equation? $$f_t = \bigl((x-a)(b-x)f_x\bigr)_x$$  A solution to this equation that starts out positive will stay positive, and the 'mass', i.e. $\int_a^b f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x$ will be constant in $t$.  This equation is parabolic in the 'interior' $a<x<b$, but, of course, degenerates at the spatial boundaries $x=a$ and $x=b$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thanks for your suggestion. I do want the long time behavior of the "modified PDE" to converge to a portion of a circle that joins $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ (which has constant curvature). I have edited my original question as well

Comment: I do not have time to do the bibliography in detail, but there are several flows defined for closed hypersurfaces (see e.g. J. Escher "Some dynamic properties of volume preserving curvature driven flows"). The volume-preserving mean curvature flow should easily be adapted to curves, but is a non-local equation (you simply add a term with the average curvature). There should be a more physical approach, working with the derivative of curvature.

Comment: Note that, since any graph of a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ that vanishes at the endpoints whose image is a portion of a circle must satisfy $|\int_a^b f\,dx |\le (b{-}a)^2\pi/8$, so if your flow preserves $\int_a^b f\,dx$ and converges to such a circular arc, then it cannot have long time existence if the initial shape does not satisfy the above inequality.

Comment: @RobertBryant thanks for your comment!

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner thanks for your comment!  I will check out these papers you mentioned! For me, the adaption might not be easy though...